# Numerical data imputation: Generative Adversarial Imputation Nets (GAIN) not reproducible?

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation, gan

I am interested in numerical data imputation problems: how to properly estimate missing values in a tabular data set (rows and columns) with missing numerical values?

In 2018, Yoon et al. proposed the GAIN framework, a Generative Adversarial Network tailored for numerical data imputation. Here is the link to the original paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.02920

Unfortunately, after many trial and error (and even after contacting the authors of the paper), it appears to me that traditional imputation methods -- like the kNN-Imputer, or MissForest -- provide better missing value estimates than GAIN. That said, the authors of GAIN claim state of the art results. I attach their Table showing the main results
[image]

This Table shows the mean normalized Root Mean Square Error (RMSE) of 6 data imputation methods using 5 numerical data sets, averaged over 10 repetitions. Parameters are optimized with 5-cross validation scheme.

My questions are... Did anyone manage to obtain satisfactory imputation results with GAIN? If yes, are those results really better than MissForest (which is one of the best numerical imputation methods in my experience)? If not, then what is that Table 2 from the paper *GAIN: Missing Data Imputation using Generative Adversarial Nets* (Yoon et al., 2018)?

Comment: I may fail to understand the question correctly. RMSE should be as small as possible and GAIN delivers the smallest RMSE in each column of your table. So what exactly is unsatisfactory with these results? Or what exactly do these RSME describe, if smaller values are considered worse?

Comment: Could you please share your version of the code with us?

Comment: @Bernhard my understanding (would be great if OP could clarify) is that OP was not able to get the results the authors are reporting in that table.

Comment: Have you implemented this yourself? If yes, good on you but their might be subtle implementation discrepancies. From simple version changes, to fine-tuning of the model. Your best bet is to e-mail the authors asking for the notebook. Plus, the PI/last author has a whole research group, someone should be able to help you.

Comment: @JohnMadden even if the OP has implemented the methodology themselves and share their code *and* is correct, that doesn't mean that other factors aren't at play for example the paper doesn't even say if the implementation was PyTorch or TensorFlow or what optimiser was used (Adam, SGD, etc.).

Comment: I used their code (https://github.com/jsyoon0823/GAIN), and even after optimal hyperparameter search, I am far from the results they present. This is why I believe that these results are fraudulent. I also contacted the authors who replied "oh sorry, we did not save the hyperparameter values".

Comment: That is poor practice but I wouldn't call it "fraudulent", also probably they fix some seed in different values that yours.

Comment: I haven't carefully reviewed the paper. It appears to be a draft submitted (not accepted, and not updated) for a 2018 ICML conference. The ICML reviewers comments would be interesting to see.  @FlorianLalande I would take what inspiration you can and move on.  I did not look to see if the authors have a subsequent version of this work published or presented at a high quality conference like ICML.

Comment: @krkeane It was accepted: http://proceedings.mlr.press/v80/yoon18a

Comment: @usεr11852 Thanks for the link.

Comment: My bounty is going to expire soon... If no one can reproduce the results provided by the authors of GAIN, should I conclude that the current consensus is that GAIN is a fraudulent method?

Comment: Here is another article which talks about the superior performance of GAIN - https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12874-021-01272-3#:~:text=Overall%2C%20GAIN%20showed%20similar%20imputation,variables%20and%20imbalanced%20categorical%20variables.